# Swift initialize Self in a static methods

Tags: swift

Having problem getting this to work, inside User.provideInstance I'm unable to initialize Self and return. Any thoughts?

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    public convenience init(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(String(self.dynamicType), inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)!
        self.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
    }
}

public protocol Deserializable {
    static func provideInstance(json: [NSObject: AnyObject]) -> Self
}

@objc(User) public class User: NSManagedObject, Deserializable {

    public static func provideInstance(json: [NSObject: AnyObject]) -> Self {
       let context = DIContainer.instance.resolve(CoreDataStack.self).managedObjectContext
       let instance = self.init(managedObjectContext: context)
       return instance
    }
}
```

Error is on `let instance = self.init(managedObjectContext: context)`:

> Constructing an object of class type Self with a metatype value must use a required initializer

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @jtbandes updated question and included error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with initializers?

```
extension NSManagedObject {
    class func provide(managedObjectContext managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Self {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(String(self.dynamicType), inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)!
        return self.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
    }
}

public protocol Deserializable {
    static func provideInstance(json: [NSObject: AnyObject]) -> Self
}

@objc(User) public class User: NSManagedObject, Deserializable {

    public static func provideInstance(json: [NSObject: AnyObject]) -> Self {
        let context = ...
        let instance = self.provide(managedObjectContext: context)
        return instance
    }
}
```

The problem with initializers is that they are not always inherited, unless they are `required`. And you cannot create a `required` initializer in an extension.

Comment: How is this any different from what I posted?

Comment: I have no forced casts there.

Answer (score 1):

As the error said, you need a required initializer to create an object, incase you subclass. Add `final` before your class to prevent this error.

Try this if you need to subclass:

```
@objc(User) public class User: NSManagedObject, Deserializable {

private static func pInstance<T>(json: [NSObject: AnyObject]) -> T {
    let context = DIContainer.instance.resolve(CoreDataStack.self).managedObjectContext
    let copy: NSManagedObject = NSManagedObject(managedObjectContext: context)
    let instance = copy as! T
    return instance
}

public static func provideInstance(json: [NSObject: AnyObject]) -> Self {
        return pInstance(json)
    }
}
```

Basically, create a helper function to create an instance of T based on the base class, NSManagedObject. Then use it the actual `provideInstance` function with the inferred type Self.

Comment: If I add final it means I won't be able to create a subclass of User anymore